# How do I create a java project that takes options at runtime (i.e. -p or -f)

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to create a jar file that can be run with options like that:

```
java -jar EXEC_NAME
java -jar -p EXEC_NAME
java -jar -p -f "path_to_file_name" EXEC_NAME
```

I know how to pass args like path_to_file_name and read them, but how can I configure my project to pass a

```
-p
```

option?

I am working in Eclipse.

Comment: I'd imagine you just put them *after* EXEC_NAME

Comment: I just read them in my project as arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java command-line arguments are passed as parameters to the `main` method. To use `java -jar`, you designate a class as your `Main-Class` in your MANIFEST.MF file. That class has a method named main, and such parameters are passed to it when it is called.

Eclipse has nothing to do with this, it's core Java behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing of note. Flags that should be passed to the application should come after "EXEC_NAME".

```
java -jar EXEC_NAME -p -f "path_to_file_name"
```

The second thing of note is your main(String[]) method. The variable there (usually named args) is an array containing all input to the right of "EXEC_NAME". So in the case of the example above. args[0] would be "-p", args[1] would be "-f", and args[2] would be "path_to_file_name".

I hope that helps you. If you need further help feel free to contact me and I will do my best to respond in a timely manner.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, you can right click on your project, select Run As / Run Configurations. There will be a tab panel named Arguments where you can set the command line arguments passed to your program when you run it from inside Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

They show up in the string array passed in in the call to main.

`public static void main(String[] args)`

Here it would be `args`

for "-p -q" you would have a two-element string array just like

```
String[] args = new String{"-p", "-q"};
```

If any of your options are complex, consider using a library instead.